# adding color column to table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a SQL table called delays

```
Delaytype   | Delayhours
Engineering |      1
Engineering |      2
Human Error |      4
```

I query this table with the following:

```
"SELECT Delaytype, SUM('Delayhours') as cnt FROM delays GROUP BY 
Delaytype;" //
```

In my PHP if I

```
echo ' <tr><td>'.$row['Delaytype'].'</td>td>'.$row 
['Delayhours'].'</td></tr>
```

I get

```
Engineering 3 
Human Error 4
```

I need a way of adding a color to this.

so

I can output

```
echo ' <tr><td>'.$row['Delaytype'].'</td><td>'.$row 
['Delayhours'].'</td><td>'.$row['color'].'</td></tr>
```

This because I need a color to place in my JSON that is associated with the Delaytype.

So the engineering gets red and the human error gets yellow.

currently I am doing :

```
sql query ... 
$myData = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$myData[] = array('value =>(int)$row['cnt'],color => '#878BB6');
```

This all works but I get the same color in every dataset when I do

```
json_encode($myData);
```

This is not a suprise to me. I want to know how I can add colors to my array with PHP. Or a SQL solution which will enable me to just creat a column.

The delaytype is not dynamic it will be a set amount so I just need to be able to get x number of colors.

UPDATE :

```
i know have two tables 
1) delays --- Delaytype | Delayhours  \\ correct case
2) delaycolors --- Delaytype | Color  \\correct case

I am getting errors with the following query : 

$result = ($con, "SELECT d.Delaytype, c.Color, SUM('Delayhours') AS cnt
FROM delays AS d
JOIN delaycolors AS c ON d.Delaytype = c.Delaytype
GROUP BY d.Delaytype; ");
```

This is giving me a fetch error suggesting the above is not working. @Barmer

Comment: How are the colors mapped to the result? Is it based on the delaytype or the number? If it was the delaytype, I would likely just add a table that maps delaytype to a color and join it in the query. If there was a table that holds all the different delaytypes you could add a color column there. If it was the number (or can be delaytype as well) something like a heatmap where based on the scale from min to max a color is assigned scaled between two colors then it would probably be done in php.

Comment: Uh, if you're already getting the delaytype from the database, which you are, can't you just in your while loop use a switch statement on `$row['Delaytype']` to figure out the value of a variable `$color`, and then put that into `$myData[]` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Add another table `DelayColors` that maps `DelayType` to colors:

```
Delaytype   | Color
Engineering | red
Human Error | yellow
```

Then use a `JOIN` in your query:

```
SELECT d.DelayType, c.color, SUM(DelayHours) AS cnt
FROM delays AS d
JOIN DelayColors AS c ON d.DelayType = c.DelayType
GROUP BY d.DelayType
```

Comment: You are just missing the group by, but essentially what I was saying in my comment above.

Comment: What does `mysqli_error($conn)` show after the query?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this :

```
SELECT Delaytype, 
    SUM('Delayhours') as cnt, 
    (SELECT CASE WHEN Delaytype = 'Engineering' THEN 'RED' ELSE 'YELLOW' END as color) 
FROM delays 
GROUP BY Delaytype
```

You can change `RED` and `YELLOW` with RGB Value. But if you making this just for get difference color between row so easy for reading. It's better done via CSS not SQL neither PHP.

Comment: While that does work, it gets pretty tough to manage when you end up with a lot of different delaytypes. Also, if you are essentially creating a table from delaytype to color then why not store it in a table.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn : Yes, you are right, better mapping the color if you have so many colors associated with that. I assume he just wanna make difference between rows. I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes the rows will go into a JSON text which is going to be place in bar graphs and charts. So I need to associate the color before it goes into the JSON

Comment: @Creaven : Follow Barmar answer, that is good practice for your case.